# Reasonable approaches to use bootstrap and angularjs together without depending on jquery

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Right now, I am taking a look at Angularjs after spending sometime playing with twitter's bootstrap. I really like bootstrap because it's easy, sleek and very mobile-friendly. Now for angularjs, I see people recommending it instead of Jquery and going as far as in saying that, DO NOT USE JQUERY AT ALL and do everything on angularjs.

This question and answers helped to shape some of my beliefs and why I should move to angularjs than jquery.

[How do I “think in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542#15012542)

Accepted answer to this question ( which is very well-detailed!) goes like this on its overall summary:

> Don't even use jQuery. Don't even include it. It will hold you back.
>   And when you come to a problem that you think you know how to solve in
>   jQuery already, before you reach for the $, try to think about how to
>   do it within the confines the AngularJS. If you don't know, ask! 19
>   times out of 20, the best way to do it doesn't need jQuery and to try
>   to solve it with jQuery results in more work for you.

Even the FAQs from angularjs website says not to use it [Angularjs FAQs](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq).

**DOM Manipulation**

> Stop trying to use jQuery to modify the DOM in
>   controllers. Really. That includes adding elements, removing elements,
>   retrieving their contents, showing and hiding them. Use built-in
>   directives, or write your own where necessary, to do your DOM
>   manipulation. See below about duplicating functionality.
>
> If you're struggling to break the habit, consider removing jQuery from
>   your app. Really. Angular has the $http service and powerful
>   directives that make it almost always unnecessary. Angular's bundled
>   jQLite has a handful of the features most commonly used in writing
>   Angular directives, especially binding to events.

The concept of angularjs seems tempting. In fact, who would not like abstracting away DOM manipulation logic? However, bootstrap makes it so much easy when you are designing web-pages but since bootstrap uses jquery, bootstrap and angularjs together means that the code and overall web-page is still dependent on jquery. Is this mixer completely undesirable? If so then, what is the best way to keep hanging to bootstrap while using angularjs? Simply saying, I don't care so much about jquery but  I like bootstrap.

I might be talking in circles here so I will try to reword what I am saying in a single sentence.

*What is the best way to use angularjs and bootstrap together without creating spaghetti code where one place is so jquery-based and next angularjs-based?Or is the idea of using bootstrap and angularjs together is conceptually against what angularjs was meant for?*

Comment: There are already tools available to achieve integration between bootstrap and angularjs, so you may not need to do this yourself at all. http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/

Comment: Or ui-bootstrap is another choice. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to integrate jQuery things in to Angular, the best approach is to wrap it in a directive. This is what [Angular-Strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) originally did, but the recent version upgrade to 2.0 completely removed those dependencies and does it all in Angular (and it is a much better product for having done so.) This is the same method that  [Angular-UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) took from day 1 and that continues today.

When you do something like this, the biggest hurdle is trying to keep things "Angular-ized" when working with the DOM. The examples that both Angular-Strap and Angular-UI can provide if you look at the underlying code are very good and should give you the right direction.